# How to pass a Hibernate entity object to another method to save to database?

Tags: java, hibernate

I have an EJB that accesses an entity and updates it with new data and sends it to a JMS queue which is then consumed by an MDB that is supposed to implement the code that saves/persists this entity to the database. Here's the EJB that accesses the entity from the database:

**AccountAccessBean.java**

```
@Stateless(mappedName = "AccountAccessBean")
@TransactionManagement(value=TransactionManagementType.CONTAINER)
@LocalBean
public class AccountAccessBean {

    @TransactionAttribute(TransactionAttributeType.REQUIRES_NEW)
    public void resigterAccountEvent() {

        Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();
        Date now = calendar.getTime();

        Configuration configuration = new Configuration().configure();
        ServiceRegistry registry = new StandardServiceRegistryBuilder()
                .applySettings(configuration.getProperties())
                .build();
        SessionFactory sessionFactory = configuration
                .addAnnotatedClass(Account.class)
                .addAnnotatedClass(Accountaccesslog.class)
                .buildSessionFactory(registry);
        Session session = sessionFactory.openSession();     
        Transaction transaction = session.beginTransaction();

        Account accountEntity = (Account) session.get(Account.class, new Integer(1));
        accountEntity.setAccessCount(accountEntity.getAccessCount() + 1);

        Accountaccesslog accountAccessLogEntity = new Accountaccesslog();
        accountAccessLogEntity.setAccessDateTime(new Timestamp(now.getTime()));
        accountEntity.addAccountaccesslog(accountAccessLogEntity);
        session.save(accountAccessLogEntity);

        transaction.commit();
        session.close();

        EntityEnqueueBean enqueueObject = new EntityEnqueueBean();
        enqueueObject.enqueueEntity(accountEntity);
    }
}
```

Currently, this Bean updates the entity and commits the changes to the database by itself. I want to move the 'commit' part of the code to the following MDB that receives the JMS message:

**AccountPersistenceMDB.java**

```
@MessageDriven(
    activationConfig = { @ActivationConfigProperty(
            propertyName = "destinationType", propertyValue = "javax.jms.Queue"),
            @ActivationConfigProperty( propertyName = "destination", 
            propertyValue ="java:/jms/queue/AccountAccessQueue")
    })
public class AccountPersitenceMDB implements MessageListener {

    public void onMessage(Message message) {
        ObjectMessage objectMessage = null;
        objectMessage = (ObjectMessage) message;
        try {
            Account accountEntity = (Account) objectMessage.getObject();
        } catch (JMSException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

I'm not sure how to implement this. Do I also need to pass the session or transaction object along with the accountEntity object? Any help or guidance is much appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

You have two operations

1. Access the entitity and send a JMS message
2. Consume the JMS message and commit to the database

**Your transaction can not and should not surround both operations**

JMS messages can

1. Get queued if the consumer(s) can't consume quick enough
2. Be consumed by multiple consumers
3. Be replayed
4. Be consumed on a different machine to the publisher

For more info on combining the JMS consumption and database commit as a single transaction see [here](http://www.javaworld.com/article/2077963/open-source-tools/distributed-transactions-in-spring--with-and-without-xa.html)